# Possible bug: Application Insights can't find some properties in some timeframes?

Tags: azure, events, azure-application-insights, metrics

When looking at Events in Application Insights to summarize collected telemetry, it is noted that a filter property 'EmptyViewItem count' is available during the last 24 hour view, but not if the timeframe is increased to 90 days.
[During last 24 hours plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKLDh.png)
[During last 90 days plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYUXr.png)

[Not all custom properties are accessable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ3Tp.png)

This seems like there is a bug with a limitation of custom properties allowed in the UI..

It is possible to access the missing custom properties from a custom query in the console. It's only the UI in Azure that is limiting.

Increasing the during timeframe somehow magically makes some custom properties disappear from the 'Split by' list, or even if I search for it in the filter. It is noted that the custom property list is listed alphabetically and only goes to 'C'. It looks like we might have hit a maximum limit of allowed custom properties, and above that is not possible to access or even search after in filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out, retrieving all metrics/custom properties under application insights is limited. It only displays a few of the available options. The missing metrics, telemetry data can be accessed using `kql` queries in the Logs console of Application insights within some timestamp and include any custom properties you choose.

I ran a sample query to retrieve the `traces logs` with the given timestamp, and it worked as expected.

You can also use `where` operator to add the custom property attribute to the following query, and it will obtain the specific custom Dimensions properties.

Note: This approach may also be limited for huge data sets. You need to optimize the query and run accordingly.

```bash
traces
| summarize by bin(timestamp, 90d)
```

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/diagnostic-search.md).